# Rails - Bootstrap dropdowns and tabs items not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i am using rails '5.2.0' version. my dropdowns working on custom html template, but dropdowns, tabs and other elements is not working in rails app. It's like there's no bootstrap.js file.

in my application.js file

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

in my haml file

```
%a.nav-link.dropdown-toggle.nav-user{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "false", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "", :role => "button"}
```

Do you think this problem has to do with javascript turbolinks?

Comment: Is that all you have in `application.js`?

Comment: can you please use and check steps from this gem https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem

Answer (score 0):

Add to application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```